# python: socketio-client not working

Tags: python-2.7

I have written this python code that uses socketio client module.

```
 from socketIO_client import SocketIO

    print "connecting to server"
    socketIO = SocketIO('localhost', 8888, transports=['websocket'])
    print "Connected"

    def sendSocketId():
        socketIO.emit('authenticate_python', "Python is connected")

    def socketDisconnect():   
        socketIO.disconnect()

    def doSomething(data):
        print "message from ui : : ", data
        socketIO.emit("msg_from_python","Message from python : : Hi! " + data)

    try:
        print socketIO.connected
        if socketIO.connected:
            sendSocketId()
        socketIO.on('msg_from_node', doSomething)
        socketIO.wait()
    except Exception as e:
        print "Exception : : ", e
        socketDisconnect()
```

But when I connect to the server and run this file, it raises the following error:

```
Python 2.7.8 (default, Jun 30 2014, 16:03:49) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
connecting to server

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\student\app.py", line 4, in <module>
    socketIO = SocketIO('localhost', 8888, transports=['websocket'])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\socketIO_client\__init__.py", line 353, in __init__
    resource, hurry_interval_in_seconds, **kw)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\socketIO_client\__init__.py", line 54, in __init__
    self._transport
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\socketIO_client\__init__.py", line 62, in _transport
    self._engineIO_session = self._get_engineIO_session()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\socketIO_client\__init__.py", line 76, in _get_engineIO_session
    transport.recv_packet())
StopIteration
>>>
```

I have no clue about this error and also there no no proper documentations as to how should we use this socketio client module.

Comment: If you have no documentation, where did you find out about the `transports` argument?

Comment: Are you on an Amazon node? I can get this to work locally on windows but get the same error as you on my EC2 box

Comment: i got a friend of mine to email me a code snippet to help understand socketio-client due to lack of matter on internet.

Comment: i am not on amazon node...what do you mean this works locally on windows?

Answer (score 2):

The issue was resolved by uninstalling socket.io 2.0.0 version and installing watever version of it matches with the socketIO-client version.

Comment: Can you please provide an example what socket.io version you needed to install and how you determined this version. I can't seem to figure this one out. Also, what is the underlying socket.io library called that is installed with pip? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: i don't remember exactly where i read it...but i can tell you the versions of both i have that work perfectly together...socketIO-client@0.7.2 and socket.io@1.7.2  install these after uninstalling the previously installed and it'll work fine...mine was python 2.7.9

Answer (score 0):

This module socketIO-client-nexus fixes issue with compatible socket version socket.io protocol 1.x

https://pypi.org/project/socketIO-client-nexus/0.7.6/

which is not backwards compatible,

if you want to communicate using socket.io protocol 0.9 please use soketIO-client 0.5.7.2

https://pypi.org/project/socketIO-client/0.5.7.2/

Don't forget to change from import socketIO-client to socketIO-client-nexus